# Where are Homebrew bottles stored online?

Tags: homebrew

From where are Homebrew bottles downloaded?

[Homebrew Documentation: Bottles](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Bottles.md) doesn't say.

I created a [Github Homebrew/brew issue #672](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/672).

Comment: See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145481 They are stored in `/usr/local/Cellar`

Comment: @learner0000 I meant where are they stored in the cloud. [Homebrew Documentation: Bottles](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Bottles.md) says, "If a bottle is available and usable it will be downloaded and poured automatically when you `brew install <formula>`." From where are bottles downloaded?

Comment: Just posted what I found in an answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of May 2021, [Bintray is no longre available](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) and bottles are hosted at GitHub
https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/packages

History and recommended reading:

- There is an excellent 2019 background article describing how to
  [Maintain your own Homebrew repository, with binary bottles](https://jonathanchang.org/blog/maintain-your-own-homebrew-repository-with-binary-bottles/), which explains the url pattern of the bottles hosted at Bintray. It's still valuable reading when dealing with older formulae and taps, even if Bintray isn't valid any more.
  The URL pattern was usually something along to `https://dl.bintray.com/<user>/bottles-<tap>`.
- In 2020, as of [Release 2.5.2](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/2.5.2), [uploading bottles to GitHub Releases](https://brew.sh/2020/11/18/homebrew-tap-with-bottles-uploaded-to-github-releases/) became supported.
- In 2021, as of [Release 3.1.0](https://brew.sh/2021/04/12/homebrew-3.1.0/), [GitHub Releases became the default location](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/11070).

#### see also

[Bottles (Binary Packages) — Homebrew Documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles)

Answer (score 6):

See the [Homebrew README](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/):

> Our bottles (binary packages) are hosted by Bintray.

[Bintray: Homebrew](https://bintray.com/homebrew)

Comment: More specifically, it seems that for version 1.2.3 of package foo for MacOS version el_capitan in repository homebrew-qux, it would download from the url `https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-qux/foo-1.2.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz`. A formula can specify a root_url in its bottle section to override the homebrew.bintray.com part of the url.

Comment: See https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/31812 for more information about how to make your own bottle location.

Comment: It seems Bintray shutdown on May 1st 2021. Homebrew bottles were moved to GitHub releases.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

`https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/<package>/blobs/sha256:<hash>`

**Longer answer:**

The following displays information about available bottles, including their URLs:

`brew info --json <formula>`

The JSON processor utility `jq` can be used to filter that output to show only the part about the bottles:

`brew info --json <formula> | jq -r ".[].bottle"`

**Longerer answer:**

`brew info` displays some information about a package.  For example:

```
$ brew info diffutils

==> diffutils: stable 3.8 (bottled)
File comparison utilities
https://www.gnu.org/s/diffutils/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/diffutils.rb
License: GPL-3.0
==> Analytics
install: 2,622 (30 days), 7,069 (90 days), 19,274 (365 days)
install-on-request: 2,286 (30 days), 5,320 (90 days), 14,990 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

$
```

`brew cat <package>` displays the package's installation source code.
This contains the `brew info` information (minus the analytics) as well as additional information, including what bottles exist and their SHA-256 hashes.  For example:

```rb
$ brew cat diffutils

class Diffutils < Formula
  desc "File comparison utilities"
  homepage "https://www.gnu.org/s/diffutils/"
  url "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/diffutils-3.8.tar.xz"
  mirror "https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/diffutils/diffutils-3.8.tar.xz"
  sha256 "a6bdd7d1b31266d11c4f4de6c1b748d4607ab0231af5188fc2533d0ae2438fec"
  license "GPL-3.0"

  bottle do
    sha256 cellar: :any_skip_relocation, arm64_ventura:  "db92359b7a7cc8eacdc1b5998df69cfa24bdaa54e02ae06f4a10bdb339c190f8"
    sha256 cellar: :any_skip_relocation, arm64_monterey: "4261be9ec928e4e841efd205eef060dc8a536b033c7d4377eae6e51f099b9eb2"
<SNIP>
    sha256 cellar: :any_skip_relocation, mojave:         "20cf9f34754b7c6c84ff790fe2240e072705a074a2af81f1ca25796801de2780"
    sha256                               x86_64_linux:   "54486cec2842e69ad311ec74cdba142385784d00d3f8cb79fd745864a19c2d7f"
  end

  def install
    system "./configure", "--disable-dependency-tracking", "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make", "install"
  end

  test do
    (testpath/"a").write "foo"
    (testpath/"b").write "foo"
    system bin/"diff", "a", "b"
  end
end

$
```

From the package name and SHA-256 of the desired bottle, we can construct the URL:

`https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/<package>/blobs/sha256:<hash>`

If that fails, we can ask Homebrew for the URLs of the bottles.
`brew info --json <formula>` displays information that neither `brew info` nor `brew cat` display, including those URLs:

```json
$ brew info --json diffutils

[
  {
    "name": "diffutils",
    "full_name": "diffutils",
    "tap": "homebrew/core",
    "oldname": null,
    "aliases": [

    ],
    "versioned_formulae": [

    ],
    "desc": "File comparison utilities",
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "homepage": "https://www.gnu.org/s/diffutils/",
    "versions": {
      "stable": "3.8",
      "head": null,
      "bottle": true
    },
    "urls": {
      "stable": {
        "url": "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/diffutils-3.8.tar.xz",
        "tag": null,
        "revision": null,
        "checksum": "a6bdd7d1b31266d11c4f4de6c1b748d4607ab0231af5188fc2533d0ae2438fec"
      }
    },
    "revision": 0,
    "version_scheme": 0,
    "bottle": {
      "stable": {
        "rebuild": 0,
        "root_url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core",
        "files": {
          "arm64_ventura": {
            "cellar": ":any_skip_relocation",
            "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:db92359b7a7cc8eacdc1b5998df69cfa24bdaa54e02ae06f4a10bdb339c190f8",
            "sha256": "db92359b7a7cc8eacdc1b5998df69cfa24bdaa54e02ae06f4a10bdb339c190f8"
          },
          "arm64_monterey": {
            "cellar": ":any_skip_relocation",
            "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:4261be9ec928e4e841efd205eef060dc8a536b033c7d4377eae6e51f099b9eb2",
            "sha256": "4261be9ec928e4e841efd205eef060dc8a536b033c7d4377eae6e51f099b9eb2"
          },
<SNIP>
          "mojave": {
            "cellar": ":any_skip_relocation",
            "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:20cf9f34754b7c6c84ff790fe2240e072705a074a2af81f1ca25796801de2780",
            "sha256": "20cf9f34754b7c6c84ff790fe2240e072705a074a2af81f1ca25796801de2780"
          },
          "x86_64_linux": {
            "cellar": "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar",
            "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:54486cec2842e69ad311ec74cdba142385784d00d3f8cb79fd745864a19c2d7f",
            "sha256": "54486cec2842e69ad311ec74cdba142385784d00d3f8cb79fd745864a19c2d7f"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "keg_only": false,
    "keg_only_reason": null,
    "options": [

    ],
    "build_dependencies": [

    ],
    "dependencies": [

    ],
    "test_dependencies": [

    ],
    "recommended_dependencies": [

    ],
    "optional_dependencies": [

    ],
    "uses_from_macos": [

    ],
    "requirements": [

    ],
    "conflicts_with": [

    ],
    "caveats": null,
    "installed": [

    ],
    "linked_keg": null,
    "pinned": false,
    "outdated": false,
    "deprecated": false,
    "deprecation_date": null,
    "deprecation_reason": null,
    "disabled": false,
    "disable_date": null,
    "disable_reason": null
  }
]


$
```

Using `jq` to filter that output to show only bottle information:

```json
$ brew info --json diffutils | jq -r ".[].bottle"

{
  "stable": {
    "rebuild": 0,
    "root_url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core",
    "files": {
      "arm64_ventura": {
        "cellar": ":any_skip_relocation",
        "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:db92359b7a7cc8eacdc1b5998df69cfa24bdaa54e02ae06f4a10bdb339c190f8",
        "sha256": "db92359b7a7cc8eacdc1b5998df69cfa24bdaa54e02ae06f4a10bdb339c190f8"
      },
      "arm64_monterey": {
        "cellar": ":any_skip_relocation",
        "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:4261be9ec928e4e841efd205eef060dc8a536b033c7d4377eae6e51f099b9eb2",
        "sha256": "4261be9ec928e4e841efd205eef060dc8a536b033c7d4377eae6e51f099b9eb2"
      },
<SNIP>
      "mojave": {
        "cellar": ":any_skip_relocation",
        "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:20cf9f34754b7c6c84ff790fe2240e072705a074a2af81f1ca25796801de2780",
        "sha256": "20cf9f34754b7c6c84ff790fe2240e072705a074a2af81f1ca25796801de2780"
      },
      "x86_64_linux": {
        "cellar": "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar",
        "url": "https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/diffutils/blobs/sha256:54486cec2842e69ad311ec74cdba142385784d00d3f8cb79fd745864a19c2d7f",
        "sha256": "54486cec2842e69ad311ec74cdba142385784d00d3f8cb79fd745864a19c2d7f"
      }
    }
  }
}

$
```

Answer (score -4):

You can find a full listing of where each package is downloaded from in the source code:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula

For example, if you want to install boost then look at `boost.rb` and find:

```
desc "Collection of portable C++ source libraries"
homepage "https://www.boost.org/"
url "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.61.0/boost_1_61_0.tar.bz2"
sha256 "a547bd06c2fd9a71ba1d169d9cf0339da7ebf4753849a8f7d6fdb8feee99b640"
```

Comment: This is the location of the source used to build the package; the question is about where the binary, compiled code is downloaded from